# Out of universe, what's the origin of the name "The Force"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, a-new-hope, george-lucas

We kind of take it for granted now after 35-odd years,  but the name **The Force** really is quite brilliant.

What's the origin and story behind (I'm assuming) George Lucas coming up with it?

Comment: *"**The Force** really is quite brilliant."*  'Opposites':  The Encourage, The Weakness, The Forced..  Meh..  I don't think it is quite so brilliant.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: what exactly do you try to tell us with that?

Comment: *"what exactly do you try to tell us with that?"*  What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @AndrewThompson everything before the "Meh.. I don't think it is quite so brilliant."

Comment: @AndrewThompson [List of Animorphs books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Animorphs_books)  =^_^=

Comment: @AndrewThompson:   I believe based on the comment upvote patterns that people really don't understand your comment.  Personally, I only barely do, maybe, but I'm not sure.   It's confusing because you're giving pseudo-antonyms for 'force' used not in the sense of that implied by 'The Force'.  And it's not clear why either?    Obviously your sense of humour is just not coming through and it's just confusing people.

Comment: The force that through the green fuse drives the flower/Drives my green age; that blasts the roots of trees/Is my destroyer./And I am dumb to tell the crooked rose/My youth is bent by the same wintry fever. ... *Dylan Thomas, 1914 - 1953*   [Lucas is no poet, probably has never read any, but this would have been a nice thought...]

Comment: Information of relevance to your question may well be posted in answer to [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142128) other question.

Answer (score 29):

### Lucas has attributed the origins of "The Force" to a 1964 abstract film called ["21-87" by Arthur Lipsett](https://letterboxd.com/film/21-87/).

> The rabbit hole goes even deeper: One of the audio sources Lipsett sampled for 21-87 was a conversation between artificial intelligence pioneer Warren S. McCulloch and Roman Kroitor, a cinematographer who went on to develop Imax. In the face of McCulloch's arguments that living beings are nothing but highly complex machines, Kroitor insists that there is something more: "Many people feel that in the contemplation of nature and in communication with other living things, they become aware of some kind of force, or something, behind this apparent mask which we see in front of us, and they call it God."
>
> **When asked if this was the source of "the Force," Lucas confirms** that his use of the term in Star Wars was "an echo of that phrase in 21-87." The idea behind it, however, was universal: "Similar phrases have been used extensively by many different people for the last 13,000 years to describe the 'life force,'" he says.
>
> *Source: Wired - [Life After Darth](http://www.wired.com/2005/05/lucas-2/?pg=3)*

Comment: Curiously enough, the German localisation uses "Die Macht" (which I'd rather translate as _power_), while one'd certainly translate "life force" with "Lebenskraft" and thus "Die Kraft" would have been more adequate...

Comment: Indeed. I tried to add that to the German Wikipedia but of course it was immediately removed..

Comment: Die Macht I'd go for power from my poor memories of German :P.

Comment: @Zommuter, I guess they where trying to advoid the else inevitable "Kraft durch Freude" jokes (and related connotations).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I never thought of that before, but could indeed be. Sad thing that so many words have a bitter taste even today...

Answer (score 11):

> Lucas has attributed the origins of "The Force" to a 1963 abstract film by Arthur Lipsett, which sampled from many sources.
>
> "Many people feel that in the contemplation of nature and in communication with other living things, they become aware of some kind of force, or something, behind this apparent mask which we see in front of us, and they call it God."
>
> <sub>- [Wikipedia "The Force"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_(Star_Wars))</sub>

There you go.

Comment: Source for this quote?

Comment: Wikipedia "The Force"

Comment: A film called 21-87

Comment: You should add that (and a link, if possible) to your answer

Comment: Sorry, relatively new to the site so forget the ediquette

Comment: @PlasmaStarfish "A film called 21-87" as in Han's line "Let's see which cell this princess of yous is in... uh... 21-87, you go an get her"? Whoa!

Comment: Whoa a wild reference appeared

Answer (score 0):

One source may be [Edward Bulwer-Lytton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Bulwer-Lytton)'s [vril](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vril). In his 1871 novel *The Coming Race*, reprinted as *Vril, the Power of the Coming Race*, Bulwer-Lytton refers to "the vril power" and "the terrible force of vril".

The novel is out of copyright and published online [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1951).

> "What is the vril?" I asked.
>
> Therewith Zee began to enter into an explanation of which I understood
>   very little, for there is no word in any language I know which is an
>   exact synonym for vril. I should call it electricity, except that it
>   comprehends in its manifold branches other forces of nature, to which,
>   in our scientific nomenclature, differing names are assigned, such as
>   magnetism, galvanism, &c. These people consider that in vril they have
>   arrived at the unity in natural energetic agencies, which has been
>   conjectured by many philosophers above ground, and which Faraday thus
>   intimates under the more cautious term of correlation:
>
> "I have long held an opinion," says that illustrious experimentalist,
>   "almost amounting to a conviction, in common, I believe, with many
>   other lovers of natural knowledge, that the various forms under which
>   the forces of matter are made manifest, have one common origin; or, in
>   other words, are so directly related and mutually dependent that they
>   are convertible, as it were into one another, and possess equivalents
>   of power in their action. These subterranean philosophers assert that
>   by one operation of vril, which Faraday would perhaps call
>   'atmospheric magnetism,' they can influence the variations of
>   temperature--in plain words, the weather; that by operations, akin to
>   those ascribed to mesmerism, electro-biology, odic force, &c., but
>   applied scientifically, through vril conductors, they can exercise
>   influence over minds, and bodies animal and vegetable, to an extent
>   not surpassed in the romances of our mystics. To all such agencies
>   they give the common name of vril."

And later

> "I have spoken so much of the Vril Staff that my reader may expect me
>   to describe it. This I cannot do accurately, for I was never allowed
>   to handle it for fear of some terrible accident occasioned by my
>   ignorance of its use; and I have no doubt that it requires much skill
>   and practice in the exercise of its various powers. It is hollow, and
>   has in the handle several stops, keys, or springs by which its force
>   can be altered, modified, or directed--so that by one process it
>   destroys, by another it heals--by one it can rend the rock, by another
>   disperse the vapour--by one it affects bodies, by another it can
>   exercise a certain influence over minds. It is usually carried in the
>   convenient size of a walking-staff, but it has slides by which it can
>   be lengthened or shortened at will. When used for special purposes,
>   the upper part rests in the hollow of the palm with the fore and
>   middle fingers protruded. I was assured, however, that its power was
>   not equal in all, but proportioned to the amount of certain vril
>   properties in the wearer in affinity, or 'rapport' with the purposes
>   to be effected."