# To what extent does Star Wars express the ideology of Rudolf Steiner?

Tags: star-wars

It has been alleged, including for example [here (in a film)](https://youtu.be/EN7y79C2E6s) and [here (in an article)](http://cosmicconvergence.org/?p=12888) by Douglas Gabriel, who claims to have been directly involved, that Star Wars creator [George Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lucas)'s wife [Marcia Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcia_Lucas), who won an Oscar for her editing of the first film, brought into it certain ideas taken from Rudolf Steiner's "spiritual science". Steiner, the founder of "anthroposophy", claimed to have received many of his ideas from the ["Akashic records"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akashic_records), and is [considered by some](http://www.quackometer.net/blog/2012/07/the-insidious-pervasiveness-of-the-cult-of-rudolf-steiner.html) to have been a highly successful charlatan.

To what extent did she put such ideas into the film?

Comment: It may be that the notion of "the force", asked about in [this other question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/110694) (not a duplicate), carried a Steinerite spin.